# IBM Worklight - Windows - "'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined"

Tags: windows, environment-variables, blackberry-10, ibm-mobilefirst

From the [BlackBerry development tutorial](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/01_05_Setting_up_your_BlackBerry_10_development_environment.pdf) I know that first I need to install the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK and then set create a WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable with the SDK path.

I do not how to create the environment variable in Eclipse. I set it through Computer-> Properties-> Advanced Settings-> Environment Variables-> User Variables but it did not worked.

When I add a BlackBerry 10 environment to my application, it gives the following error in the Eclipse Worklight console:

> E: blackberry10 build failed: The 'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined. See Worklight Information Center for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable is created in the manner you have described - a dedicated environment variable with the name `WEBWORKS_HOME` and the value, for example: `C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11`.

- There is no need to create it in Eclipse
- You can check that it correctly exists by opening a CMD window and typing `set`

Re-start Eclipse and the Build operation should now pass for the BlackBerry 10 environment.

Comment: thankyou for the help. I downloaded BB SDK 10 and in Enviroment Variable i set Variable Name: WEBWORKS_HOME and Variable Value:%WEBWORKS_HOME%C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11. but its not working

Comment: BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11 is the folder which contain BB jars and libs

Comment: What is that "%WEBWORKS_HOME%" doing in the path? It should be only from c:\ until the folder you've mentioned (it is the root folder).

Comment: WEBWORKS_HOME is not added to the path.  Instead, it must be added as a separate environment variable.  I hit this same problem and this solved it.  Also, note that you don't type "path" to see all the environment variables, you type "set" and all of them will be shown including WEBWORKS_HOME

Comment: Clarified this some more in my answer.

Comment: I have tried everything .Same error is also coming for me what should i do

Comment: You should open a new question and add all details and errors you get. Your comment is not helpful.