# IBM Worklight 6.0 - WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable not working

Tags: environment-variables, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, windows-7-x64

I tried the suggestion given in [IBM Worklight - Windows - "'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment variable is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739668/ibm-worklight-windows-webworks-home-environment-variable-is-undefined#new-answer), but i am still getting an error:

> FWLST1040E: blackberry10 build failed: the 'WEBWORKS_HOME' environment
>   variable is not defined. Add an environment variable named
>   'WEBWORKS_HOME' pointing to the WebWorks SDK root folder

I am on windows 7(64 bit) and Worklight is version 6.0.

When i type "set" in command prompt i can see `WEBWORKS_HOME=C:\BB10` which is the correct location and root of the SDK.

I have restarted Eclipse but the error message is shown still.

Comment: Add to the question what that you see after typing "set".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to creating the environment variable `WEBWORKS_HOME` and having it point to the root folder of the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK,

Also make sure that this variable has been added to the `PATH` variable value.
Meaning, that the value for `PATH` should now be something like this:

```
C:\something;somethingElse;anotherSomething;%WEBWORKS_HOME%
```

If that doesn't work still, try without the %'s.

Comment: It resolved. Also, i had to restart my PC as the environment variable changes are not reflected without restart on my windows 7, 64 bit.